# Not receiving clear list notifications from Call log

Tags: c++, mobile, symbian, nokia, s60

I have been using `CLogViewRecent` and `MLogViewChangeObserver` to monitor call log on S60 5th edition phones.

`MLogViewChangeObserver` has three functions:

```
virtual void HandleLogViewChangeEventAddedL(TLogId aId, TInt aViewIndex, TInt aChangeIndex, TInt aTotalChangeCount);
virtual void HandleLogViewChangeEventChangedL(TLogId aId, TInt aViewIndex, TInt aChangeIndex, TInt aTotalChangeCount);
virtual void HandleLogViewChangeEventDeletedL(TLogId aId, TInt aViewIndex, TInt aChangeIndex, TInt aTotalChangeCount);
```

However, only the first two get called regularly, while `HandleLogViewChangeEventDeletedL` gets called only sometimes.

E.g. `HandleLogViewChangeEventDeletedL` is not called when I choose "Clear List" from the menu in "Received calls" list in Call log application.

Can anyone point to the reason why this is happening, and how to correct this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the [Symbian^3 logcli source](http://developer.symbian.org/xref/oss/xref/Symbian3/sf/os/persistentdata/loggingservices/eventlogger/LogCli/), "list cleared" is an event different from "event deleted". It's not reflected in the `MLogViewChangeObserver` callback mixin, only in `MLogViewChangeObserverInternal` as `HandleLogViewChangeEventLogClearedL()`. That's why it's happening. Sorry, cannot offer you a workaround, short of implementing your own logsrv client that handles `ELogChangeTypeLogCleared` change types the way you want.

Maybe you could describe what you are trying to achieve on the big picture level so it could be possible to offer other alternatives.

Comment: Thank you for point me to the source code. My application needs to be in sync with call log, so when call log gets deleted, my internal call list should be cleared too.